# Why can't I change the size of my spheres in Unity?

Tags: unity

I started to learn Unity. Now I make something like a solar system. I have one problem. What are the min and max sizes of the sphere? E.g. I have a radius of the Sun - 1.5 but it shows like the Sun has radius 1, I can't make bigger. But also I have the Earth with 0.01 size and the Moon with 0.009. But I can't make the Mercury with 0.03 radius.
So why when I'm creating a new sphere now I have only radius 1 and can't change it in Scene window?  [image: Unity Planets Sizes]

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be changing the collider, not the actual transform. The transform reflects the position, rotation ***and size*** of your game object. The *collider* reflects the invisible barrier around your object that flags potential collision events.

### The Transform - the position, scale and size of our object

The transform is where you want to be directing changes to the overall size of your spheres. You can see the obvious distinction, below. The sphere mesh, itself, is the blue mesh made up of triangles.

[image: A sphere being squashed through manipulation in the transform component.]

In case you find yourself in a different predicament of confusion, the transform values also inherit from parent game objects. In the above example, you can see that the sphere has a scale of (2,1,1). This make the object extend 2 unit along the X-axis, and 1 unit along the Y-axis and Z-axis. Un-parented, we can say that it multiplies its values by 1. Parented to another game object, the transform values multiply by the transform values of the parent. Hopefully this does not sound too confusing, as it is an important feature. It allows you to easily lock objects together, create deliberate rotational pivots, or any number of useful reliance. It is also a common concept in general 3D design.

In the example, below, we have a second sphere with the scale of (0.5, 0.5, 0.5). When I parent our original sphere to the second sphere, its scale changes to (4, 2, 2) to retain the same size. This is because it now inherits from the second sphere, making its *world* transform (0.5*4, 0.5*2, 0.5*2), or the original (2, 1, 1). You will see this is also reflected in the position and rotation, with the parent values acting as the origin, or local (0, 0, 0) position/rotation.

[image: Parented to another object, the sphere changes its transform values to represent its current position and size based off the transform values inherited from the parent.]

## The Collider - the collision barrier around your object

The collider is an invisible barrier around your object, used to calculate collision. Ideally you would want to wrap this around your object, as tight as possible. There is often some allowance in how loose the collider is, generally in favour of using simpler shapes. Simpler shapes are quicker for calculating collision.

The Collider dimensions are relative to the actual object. In the above example, we see the collider as a perfect circle around our actual sphere. With a radius of 0.5, a sphere collider will *always* wrap around your sphere mesh. In the case of not having a perfect sphere, due to having different X,Y and Z scale values, the collider will wrap to the largest axis. We can see this in the above picture, where the collider has wrapped to the X-axis, and extended past the spheres Y-axis and (unseen in the example) Z-axis. For this reason, you should generally never have to alter the sphere collider, in the project described above.

### Unity Default Values

It is worth mentioning that by default, 1 unit is intended to represent 1 meter or 1 kilogram, depending on the context being distance or weight. It certainly does not have to, after all, its your project. That said, its worth knowing that this is the default interpretation Unity will take into account when calculating things such as physics.

If you find any abnormalities in your project, as a result, [it is recommended](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129890/why-cant-i-change-the-size-of-my-spheres-in-unity) that you play around with your project settings to find a comfortable balance. You can access your project settings by going to the top menu bar, and selecting **Edit > Project Settings**. From there, you can select **Physics** for 3D physics, **Physics2D** for 2D physics, or **Audio** for related audio settings such as Doppler effect.

Answer (score 2):

From the image i see that you're changing the sphere collider not the sphere scale , sphere collider has nothing to do with sphere rendering, Try to change the Scale instead.

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of an object, change the X, Y and Z scale in the `Transform` component. The `Collider` component governs how the object interacts with other objects. When you want the *physical* surface of your sphere to be identical to its *visual* surface, leave its radius at 1.0.